# Makefile:6: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile

```
HEADERS = schedule.h 

default: papcmp

program.o: schedule.c $(HEADERS)
    gcc -g -lnuma -lm -pthread schedule.c -lutil -lz -o schedule.o

program: schedule.o
    gcc schedule.o -o papcmp

clean:
    -rm -f schedule.o
    -rm -f papcmp
    -rm -f *.log dump.gz
```

This is the first time i'm trying to create a make file. and it looks like there is an error. Could you help me with it? The line that is in **`bold`** has the error according to the output.

Comment: Whey do you have ** in your file? Remove those. And it looks like you are trying to build program.o but tell it to output schedule.o

Comment: I don't have the **. That's how SO represents **Bold** for code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [makefile:4: \*\*\* missing separator. Stop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)

Comment: in my case Makefile plugin was not installed on android studio..

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Make is *very* picky about spaces vs. tabs. Command lines absolutely must be indented with a single tab, and *not* spaces. You may need to adjust your editor to generate tab characters.

Comment: Ok. Let me try.

Could you also look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24142856/usage-of-pseudo-terminal-c please

Comment: This is what I get now:
make: *** No rule to make target `papcmp', needed by `default'.  Stop.

Comment: @pistal: that would be a completely different problem. (Hint: `papcmp` isn't a target in your Makefile).

Comment: Ok. Got that. Thanks! Any idea how to solve the other issue? been stuck with it for a while now.

Comment: That is also a completely different problem...please don't drag one problem into another.

Comment: Alright. I'll wait for the timer to go away so that I mark your answer. In case, you can help me with the other one, please do so.

Answer (score 0):

## Make `TAB` to make it work!

---

### Example working code with `TAB` symbol as orange line

[image: working version]

---

## Original code with spaces highlighted in Notepad++:

[image: your code in Notepad++ with spaces highlighted]