# Getting error when executing Make File with if condition

Tags: shell, unix, makefile

I have tried to execute a simple make file with if loop condition

```
PROJDIR:=..
$(info TEXT selected is $(TEXT))
if [ -d "$(PROJDIR)/test" ]; then
  BUILDTOOLDIR?=$(PROJDIR)/test
fi
```

After executing , i am getting error

```
Makefile:5: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

I have searched some of the similar query

[Makefile:6: *** missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145650/makefile6-missing-separator-stop)

[makefile:4: *** missing separator. Stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16931770/makefile4-missing-separator-stop)

I have tried some of the solutions

1. With tabs.
2. with slashes `/`

But nothing got worked for me . Any help ? Something i have missed here ?

Comment: The code shown is not a valid `makefile`.  Most of it looks like basic `shell` syntax.

Comment: You can learn the basics of writing makefiles in the [GNU Make Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html),
section [2 An Introduction to Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction) and
section [3 Writing Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Makefiles).